# Composing uint8_t with int + char

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm writing a library for Arduino, and I've run into this problem:
I need to create an `uint8_t` variable to define an analog pin (`Ax`) and I'm not being able to do it in an easy way.

This more or less illustrates my problem, `_pin` being an `uint8_t`:

```
sensortemp::sensortemp(int pin)     // Constructor
{
    // being _pin an uint8_t
    // _pin = A0 if pin = 0;
    // _pin = A1 if pin = 1;
    // etc.
}
```

The only working solution I've found is one I do NOT want to use...

```
sensortemp::sensortemp(int pin)
{
   if(pin == 0)
    _pin = A0;
   else if(pin == 1)
    _pin = A1;
   else if(pin == 2)
    _pin = A2;
   else if(pin == 3)
    _pin = A3
}
```

I hope someone can help me with this `uint8_t` problem :)
Thanks in advance

Comment: What? I don't see any `uint8_t` here or any problem with it..

Comment: Why can't you pass `A0` et alia to the method?

Comment: what type for `_pin` and `Ax`?

Comment: I made an edit, sorry I missed to point out the uint8_t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no problem with type conversion and what you're looking for is:

```
_pin = pin + A0;
```

optionally with a range check. Also, if `_pin` is `uint8_t`, then make `pin` the same too. Throw in a `static_cast` if you're getting a warning:

```
_pin = static_cast<uint8_t>(pin + A0);
```

Arduino pins are defined as integers, starting from `A0` constant (e.g. `14` for Arduino Uno or `54` for Arduino Mega - because of more digital pins that are listed before). They are all defined to be consecutive integers, so you just have to add the offset (`pin`) with the first analog pin (`A0`).

---

<sup>You might want to use [member initializer list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list) for best practice if you're not going to check for invalid `pin`.</sup>

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thank you!
I'll take my time to learn about uint8_t as soon as possible.

Comment: I didn't knew either that pins A0, A1, ... were integers, then there's no reason to use _pin as uint8_t.

Comment: @Eduardo They are actually `uint8_t`, which is also an integer - it's not only `int`.

Comment: I definitely have to read about uint8_t whenever I have time, thanks again.